# Insert an Incremental Dynamic Value in Visio

Tags: ms-office, visio, dynamic-variables

I have a large spreadsheet with rows that do get rearranged a few times of a year (few hundred lines). I also have a Visio document that basically maps these rows with simple boxes and connectors. Boxes are basically a value from one column (say column B), and connectors represent values from another column (say column F).

I have also added row Id's on each of these connectors, aside from the value column F, however, as I said, the rows do get rearranged, so I was wondering if there was a way to create a variable and use it as part of a text in each of these connectors to go incrementally. This is to avoid modifying the row Id's when new ones are added, or they get rearranged.

I'm not looking for Visio to parse the Excel sheet. Simply to have a dynamically incremental variable that I can use to shift these numbers up and down in my Visio, so when I see the old value of, e.g. Val_from_Column_F (3), and now the same row has been moved to, say, row 12, now I need to display, Val_from_Column_F (12) -- a difference of 9. And have every other value in Visio to get incremented by 9 accordingly. That way, every row after 3, gets incremented equally by 9 and represents the current rows in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi, I think it is a more difficult way. You need analize cell values and add new rows where it necessary. Easier way - delete old table and re-generate it

Comment: I am not sure I understand very well what you're trying to do, but if your 'variable' is a cell in the shapesheet, then you can use Visio's Fields to display a shapesheet cell value as part of the shape text.  You can just edit the text of the shape, then go to Insert->Field, and pick that cell, and it'll insert that into the shape text.